Best cloud platform for uploading and fetching
I'm working on a course platform like Udemy using the mern stack. What do you think is the best cloud storage or video streaming platform that is cost effective.
Taking into account video URL protection, i.e people outside the platform can't access the URL even if a friend shared it with them.
I'm thinking of mux, but am not sure about it.
